# Force BottomSheetFlatList open from first position every time useCallback called in react-native-bottom-sheet

Tags: react-native

I am using react-native-bottom-sheet with BottomSheetFlatList.

I want to open BottomSheetFlatList at initialPosition every time it opened but I am not able to achieve that. When I open it it's always open at last scrolling position.

```
<BottomSheet
        ref={bottomSheetRef}
        index={0}
        snapPoints={snapPoints}
        enableDismissOnClose={true}
        handleIndicatorStyle={{display: 'none'}}
        handleStyle={{padding: 0}}>
        <View style={{backgroundColor: '#b2b2b2', alignItems: 'center'}}>
          {!isOpen && (
            <Pressable onPress={() => handleSnapPress(1)}>
              <Image
                source={IconCollapse}
                style={{width: 30, height: 20, backgroundColor: '#b2b2b2'}}
              />
            </Pressable>
          )}

          {isOpen && (
            <Pressable onPress={() => handleClosePress()}>
              <Image
                source={IconExpand}
                style={{width: 30, height: 20, backgroundColor: '#b2b2b2'}}
              />
            </Pressable>
          )}
        </View>
        <View style={{backgroundColor: '#b2b2b2'}}>
          <Text
            style={{
              color: 'white',
              fontSize: 20,
              textTransform: 'uppercase',
              paddingStart: 10,
            }}>
            Select Zone
          </Text>
          <View
            style={{
              borderBottomColor: '#fff',
              borderBottomWidth: 1,

              marginEnd: 10,
              marginStart: 10,
            }}
          />
        </View>
        <BottomSheetFlatList
          data={zoneList}

          keyExtractor={(item, index) => `${index}`}
          renderItem={renderItem}
          
         
                    contentContainerStyle={styles.contentContainer}
        />
      </BottomSheet>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
you can try 
this.flatListRef.scrollToOffset({ animated: true, offset: 0 });

hope this is work
```

Answer (score 0):

use Prop `enableDismissOnClose`

as mentioned [here](https://gorhom.github.io/react-native-bottom-sheet/modal/props/#enabledismissonclose)

Comment: It's not working.

Comment: are you using @gorhom/bottom-sheet?

Comment: yes let me share the code

Comment: you should use `BottomSheetModal` in order to use this prop

Answer (score 0):

As [Mohammad Momin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74716041/7178860) said you can try `scrollToIndex({index: 0, offset: 0})`.

In order to do that you have to declare a `ref` for your `FlatList` and also specify the `getItemLayout` prop. Then you can call [`scrollToIndex`](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#scrolltoindex).
So every time that you open the bottomSheet you have to call `scrollToIndex`.

The full working example I created is available in this [github repositor](https://github.com/MohammadAzimi/GorhomBottomSheetFirstPosition) which is something like this:

```
export const CustomBottomSheet = forwardRef(({
    zoneList = [],
    selectedZone,
    onZoneSelected
}, ref) => {

    const bottomSheetRef = useRef(null);
    const flatListRef = useRef(null);

    const scrollToItem = () => {
        if (!selectedZone) return;
        if (zoneList.length < 1) return;
        // find item index
        const index = zoneList.findIndex(value => value.id === selectedZone?.id);
        // scroll to destination index
        // it's better to set animated to true (experimental)
        flatListRef.current.scrollToIndex({
            animated: true,
            index: index, // 0
        })
        console.log('scrollToItem called by index:' + index)
    }

    const handleSnapPress = (index = 0) => {
        bottomSheetRef.current.snapToIndex(index);
        // call this method after each time user opens the bottom sheet
        scrollToItem();
    }

    const handleClosePress = () => {
        bottomSheetRef.current.snapToIndex(index);
    }

    const renderItem = ({ item }) => {
        return (
            <ListItem
                {...item}
                onPress={() => onZoneSelected(item)}
                isSelected={item.id === selectedZone?.id}
            />
        )
    }

    const getItemLayout = (_, index) => (
        {
            length: ListItem.HEIGHT,
            offset: (ListItem.HEIGHT + ListItem.VERTICAL_SPACING) * index,
            index: index,
        }
    )

    // forwarding methods via ref
    useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
        open: handleSnapPress,
        close: handleClosePress,
        snapToIndex: handleSnapPress,
    }));

    return (
        <BottomSheet
            ref={bottomSheetRef}
            index={-1}
            snapPoints={SNAP_POINTS}
            enableDismissOnClose={true}
            // onChange={handleOnChange}
            enablePanDownToClose={true}
            >
            <View style={{ backgroundColor: '#b2b2b2', alignItems: 'center', marginTop: 16 }}>
                <Text
                    style={{
                        color: 'white',
                        fontSize: 20,
                        textTransform: 'uppercase',
                        paddingStart: 10,
                    }}>
                    {'Select Zone'}
                </Text>
            </View>
            <BottomSheetFlatList
                // add ref and getItemLayout in order to use scrollToIndex method
                ref={flatListRef}
                getItemLayout={getItemLayout}
                data={zoneList}
                keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
                renderItem={renderItem}
                contentContainerStyle={styles.contentContainer}
            />
        </BottomSheet>
    )
})
```